# Add a value to a delete link in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, hyperlink, link-to

I currently have the following link_to in my Rails application:

```
<%= link_to 'Remove this Person', @person, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete, :class => 'important', :class => "minimal important" %>
```

I would like to add the person's name in place of the "this person" for the link.

I don't appear to be able to do:

```
<%= link_to 'Remove <%= @person.name %>', @person, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete, :class => 'important', :class => "minimal important" %>
```

I have seen this example online:

```
<%= link_to(@profile) do %>
    <strong><%= @profile.name %></strong> -- <span>Check it out!</span>
  <% end %>
  # => <a href="/profiles/1">
         <strong>David</strong> -- <span>Check it out!</span>
       </a>
```

Any ideas on how to convert that into a delete link, with the confirmation box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
<%= link_to "Remove #{@person.name}", @person, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete, :class => 'important', :class => "minimal important" %>
```

Comment: I suppose that convert that to delete isn't possible because delete link is really more difficult than others